# Taking YouTube links out of a list of GitHub repo READMEs

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, url, git

I have a .csv file that contains student GitHub repository assignment submissions. I made a script to go to each repository and extract the YouTube video that they must have provided in their README file.

The structure of the CSV file is as follows:

```
Timestamp,Name,Student Number,Git Repo link
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import csv
import github3
import time
import re
import argparse
from secrets import username, password

# API rate limit for authenticated requests is way higher than anonymous, so login.
gh = github3.login(username, password=password)
# gh = github3.GitHub() # Anonymous


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filepath", type=str, metavar="filepath", help="Filepath to the input csv file.")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args = vars(args)  # Turn into dict-like view.

    return args


def get_row_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return sum(1 for row in csv.reader(file))


def get_repositories(link):
    if gh.rate_limit()['resources']['search']['remaining'] == 0:
        print("API rate exceeded, sleeping for {0} seconds.".format(gh.rate_limit()['resources']['search']['reset'] - int(time.time()+1)))
        time.sleep(gh.rate_limit()['resources']['search']['reset'] - int(time.time()+1))

    return gh.search_repositories(link.replace("https://github.com/", "", 1), "", 1)


def main():
    filepath = parse_args()['filepath']
    if not filepath.endswith('.csv'):
        print("Input file must be a .csv file.")
        exit()

    p = re.compile(r"http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?") # From http://stackoverflow.com/a/3726073/6549676
    row_counter = 0
    row_count = get_row_count(filepath)

    with open(filepath, 'r') as infile, open(filepath[:3] + "_ytlinks.csv", "w") as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        next(reader, None)  # Skip header

        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(["Youtube Link", "Name", "GitHub Link"])  # Write header

        for row in reader:
            for repo in get_repositories(row[3]):
                readme = repo.repository.readme().decoded
                if not readme:
                    readme = "No Youtube link found."

                if type(readme) is bytes:
                    readme = readme.decode('utf-8')

                ids = p.findall(readme)
                if len(ids) != 0:
                    ids = ids[0]

                ids = [x for x in ids if x]

                for _id in ids:
                    writer.writerow(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={0}'.format(_id), row[1], row[3]])

                if len(ids) == 0:
                    writer.writerow(['No Youtube Link Found', row[1], row[3]])

            print('Processed row {0} out of {1}'.format(row_counter, row_count))
            row_counter += 1

    print("Finished.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are some concerns/suggestions:

- you are reading the file twice - once to get the row count and when reading the links. And, you don't need to initialize the `csv.reader` to get the row count, simply [use `sum()` over the lines in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108605/771848). You would probably need to use [`infile.seek(0)` after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696472/seek-function) getting the count and before initializing the csv reader
- use [`_` for the throw-away variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) (when counting the number of lines)
- `if len(ids) == 0:` can be simplified as `if not ids:`
- it looks like you don't need `.findall()` and should use `.search()` method since you are up to a single match
- if there is a single repository link per line, you probably should have `get_repository()` method instead of `get_repositories()` and avoid the `for repo in get_repositories(row[3]):` loop - remember, ["Flat is better than nested"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
- instead of handling the enumeration with `row_counter` manually, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- instead of accessing the current row fields by index - e.g. `row[1]` or `row[3]`, you can unpack the row in the for loop, something like (an example, I don't know your actual CSV input format):

  ```
  for index, username, _, github_link in reader:
  ```

  Or, you can use a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) - accessing the fields by column names instead of indexes would improve readability - e.g. `row["github_link"]` instead of `row[3]`
- you don't have to convert the `args` to a dictionary - return `args` and then access the arguments using a dot notation - e.g. `args.filepath`

Answer (score 4):

`str` is already the default type of any variable parsed with `argparse`. Also the default `metavar` is just the name itself.

The cool thing about `argparse` is that it allows you to use custom variable parsing functions as type. So you could put the file type (or actually only file ending) check there:

```
import os


def csv_file(filepath):
    if not filepath.endswith('.csv'):
        raise ValueError("Input file must be a .csv file.")
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        raise FileNotFoundError("Could not find file {}".format(filepath)
    return filepath


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filepath", type=csv_file, help="Filepath to the input csv file.")
    return vars(parser.parse_args())
```

If an exception is raised in the type function, argparse will catch it, display it and exit the program.

Comment: Awesome use of `argparse` custom types! Fits the problem nicely.